# How to open kernel module in abap?

Tags: abap

I tried to open this kernel module by double click on it, but it does not work. I could not find answer in internet either.

Do you know how could I check what is inside of this kernel module/open it?

[image]

Comment: Kernel modules are calls to c functions. They are already compiled so viewing them would be nearly impossible (for ABAP developers). Why do you need to look inside?

Comment: I wanted to find out the table to which system id is written down, as it contains local server connections

Comment: @Denis You are barking up the wrong tree. This is the System UUID (unique identifier) and has nothing to do with system id and local server connections. What are you looking for exactly? Probably you see something in one of the transactions and want to know from which table it comes from, don't you?

Comment: Hi Jagger, you are right, I was digging in wrong direction. I tried to check which table is used and then try to do "where-used list" for this table.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Apply for a developer position at SAP and, once you've been accepted, access the internal kernel source code. That part is closed-source (at least at the time of this answer) and not available for customer or partner review.

Comment: Could you provide more details on how to get to this "once you've been accepted" phase? ;)

Comment: @gkubed I can provide you the info, my former colleague is working on NWDS at Walldorf now :)

Comment: Haha, thank you @Suncatcher, I better brush up on my German before pursuing such a thing realistically!